# FFMPEG script does not run in php

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to let users compress their videos in my website. website is used in a intranet environment.

I am using this script to compress videos using php. Users are allowed to upload videos file from any location but the code is not working.

```
$filePath = dirname(__FILE__);
shell_exec("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i C:\\$filePath -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 output.mp4 > logfile.txt 2>&1");
```

logfile.txt

```
ffmpeg version N-76822-g12a419d Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
  libavcodec     57. 16.100 / 57. 16.100
  libavformat    57. 19.100 / 57. 19.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 15.100 /  6. 15.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
C:\C:\wamp\www\testNxServer\trynewnew\menu\stream\video: Invalid argument
```

full source code

upload.php

```
    <?php

$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$filePath = dirname(__FILE__);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))

&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
          shell_exec("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i C:\\$filePath -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 output.mp4 > logfile.txt 2>&1"); 
          //shell_exec("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i video.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 output.mp4 > logfile.txt 2>&1");
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Comment: hi. if you mean the logfile.txt it is empty.. no error..

Comment: I mean `stdout`.  What get's `echo`ed?

Comment: What is the output of your `PHP` script?

Comment: The output i am getting now the video file is copied to upload folder without compressing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100327/discussion-between-mick-jack-and-raphael-rafatpanah).

Answer (score 0):

For this section of code:

```
shell_exec("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i C:\\$filePath -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 output.mp4 > logfile.txt 2>&1"); 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

You can see in the log file you posted that it's trying to open C:\C:\...\video

So you don't need the extra C:\\ in the shell query.  Also,  you should put the input file in quotes in case of spaces. finally, the move_uploaded_file() call seems to be moving the originally uploaded file and not the output.mp4 file made by ffmpeg.

So perhaps this would be more like what you need?

```
shell_exec("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i \"$filePath\" -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 \"upload\\{$_FILES['file']['name']}\" > logfile.txt 2>&1");
```

Comment: i am getting Permission denied on the output

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that move_uploaded_file isn't allowed on files that weren't uploaded by php. Try getting ffmpeg to output directly to where you want it, I'm not sure what the full directory should be so you can put that in where you need it. See the edited ffmpeg call.

Comment: still getting permission denied.. changing the file-path to video.mp4 and it work but user will have to store video.mp4 in the same location.. any help to let users upload from any location?